# How can I view the contents of a hash in Perl6 (in a fashion similar to the Perl 5 modules Data::Dump or Data::Show)?

Tags: perl, hash, raku

In Perl 5, if I want to see the contents of a hash, I can use [`Data::Show`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Show), [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump), or [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper).

For example:

```
use Data::Show;

my %title_for = (
    'Book 1' => {
        'Chapter 1' => 'Introduction',
        'Chapter 2' => 'Conclusion',
    },
    'Book 2' => {
        'Chapter 1' => 'Intro',
        'Chapter 2' => 'Interesting stuff',
        'Chapter 3' => 'Final words',
   }
);

show(%title_for);
```

Which outputs:

```
======(  %title_for  )======================[ 'temp.pl', line 15 ]======

    {
      "Book 1" => { "Chapter 1" => "Introduction", "Chapter 2" => "Conclusion" },
      "Book 2" => {
                    "Chapter 1" => "Intro",
                    "Chapter 2" => "Interesting stuff",
                    "Chapter 3" => "Final words",
                  },
    }
```

Is there anything equivalent in Perl 6? I thought I remember Damian Conway discussing this feature at YAPC 2010, but I have since lost my notes and Googling hasn't helped.

```
use v6;

my %title_for = (
  "Book 1" => { "Chapter 1" => "Introduction", "Chapter 2" => "Conclusion" },
  "Book 2" => {
                "Chapter 1" => "Intro",
                "Chapter 2" => "Interesting stuff",
                "Chapter 3" => "Final words",
              },
);

%title_for.say;
```

The closest thing that I found to working is `%title_for.say`. However, it seems messy for nested hashes:

```
Book 1 => Chapter 1 => Introduction, Chapter 2 => Conclusion, Book 2 => Chapter 1 => Intro, Chapter 2 => Interesting stuff, Chapter 3 => Final words
```

I'm using Perl6 running on [MoarVM](http://www.moarvm.com) from the [January 2015 release of Rakudo Star](http://rakudo.org/downloads/star/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Perl6 docs](http://doc.perl6.org/language/5to6#Data%3A%3ADumper) seem to recommend using `.perl` on the data structure, but it looks like pretty-printing requires extra work:

> #### Given:
>
> ```
> my @array_of_hashes = (
>     { NAME => 'apple',   type => 'fruit' },
>     { NAME => 'cabbage', type => 'no, please no' },
> );
> ```
>
> #### Perl 5
>
> ```
> use Data::Dumper;
> $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
> print Dumper \@array_of_hashes; # Note the backslash.
> ```
>
> #### Perl 6
>
> ```
> say @array_of_hashes.perl; # .perl on the array, not on its reference.
> ```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to remember: `.perl`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have since made a [PrettyDump](https://github.com/briandfoy/perl6-PrettyDump) module that might be handy:

```
use v6;
use PrettyDump;

my %title_for = (
  "Book 1" => { "Chapter 1" => "Introduction", "Chapter 2" => "Conclusion" },
  "Book 2" => {
                "Chapter 1" => "Intro",
                "Chapter 2" => "Interesting stuff",
                "Chapter 3" => "Final words",
              },
);

say PrettyDump.new.dump: %title_for;
```

With output:

```
Hash={
    :Book 1(Hash={
        :Chapter 1("Introduction"),
        :Chapter 2("Conclusion")
    }),
    :Book 2(Hash={
        :Chapter 1("Intro"),
        :Chapter 2("Interesting stuff"),
        :Chapter 3("Final words")
    })
}
```

There are some formatting options you can give to `PrettyDump` too.

Answer (score 2):

[dd](https://docs.perl6.org/programs/01-debugging#Dumper_function_dd) for Data Dump in rakudo.

```
my @array_of_hashes = (
    { NAME => 'apple',   type => 'fruit' },
    { NAME => 'cabbage', type => 'no, please no' },
);
dd @array_of_hashes;
```