# How to print an object, type in nqp

Tags: raku, nqp

How to print an object in NQP ? (For debugging purposes)

- It is easy in Raku:

  1. [say](https://docs.raku.org/routine/say) that is calling [gist](https://docs.raku.org/routine/gist) in its short loop [code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/9429728cbd89e58bc85d88281985e44229fbcddb/src/core.c/io_operators.pm6#L24)
  2. [dd](https://docs.raku.org/programs/01-debugging#Dumper_function_dd) The tiny Data Dumper as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60707981/2544873)

```
class Toto { has $.member = 42; }
class Titi { has $.member = 41; has $.toto = Toto.new }
my $ti = Titi.new;
say $ti;
# Titi.new(member => 41, toto => Toto.new(member => 42))
dd $ti;
# Titi $ti = Titi.new(member => 41, toto => Toto.new(member => 42))
```

- It seems more complicated in NQP

```
class Toto { has $!member; sub create() {$!member := 42}};
class Titi { has $!member; has $!toto; sub create() {$!member := 41; $!toto := Toto.new; $!toto.create; }}
my $ti := Titi.new;
say($ti);
```

```
Cannot stringify this object of type P6opaque (Titi)
```

Of course, no `.gist` method, the [code](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/bb00e60e6709c82021fd822e87ec651094b66b5c/src/core/IO.nqp#L280-L283) calls `nqp::encode` which finally expects a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reducing the problem to an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
class foo {}
say(foo.new); # Cannot stringify ...
```

Simplifying the solution:

```
class foo { method Str () { 'foo' } }
say(foo.new); # foo
```

In summary, add a `Str` method.

This sounds simple but there's a whole lot of behind-the-scenes stuff to consider/explain.

## nqp vs raku

The above solution is the same technique raku uses; when a value is expected by a routine/operation to be a string, but isn't, the language behavior is to attempt to coerce to a string. Specifically, see if there's a `Str` method that can be called on the value, and if so, call it.

In this case [NQP's `NQPMu`](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/50bb7de4da1e90907f42fa86ee68884e79c71811/src/core/NQPMu.nqp), which is way more barebones than [raku's `Mu`](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/50bb7de4da1e90907f42fa86ee68884e79c71811/src/core/NQPMu.nqp), doesn't provide any default `Str` method. So a solution is to manually add one.

More generally, NQP is a pretty hostile language unless you know raku fairly well and have gone thru [A course on Rakudo and NQP internals](https://github.com/edumentab/rakudo-and-nqp-internals-course).

And once you're up to speed on the material in that course, I recommend you consider the IRC channels [#raku-dev](https://kiwiirc.com/nextclient/irc.freenode.com/#raku-dev) and/or [#moarvm](https://kiwiirc.com/nextclient/irc.freenode.com/#moarvm) as your first port of call rather than SO (unless your goal is specifically to increase SO coverage of nqp/moarvm).

## Debugging the compiler code

As you will have seen, the NQP code you linked calls `.say` on a filehandle.

That then calls [this method](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/bb00e60e6709c82021fd822e87ec651094b66b5c/src/core/IO.nqp#L187-L189).

That method's body is `$str ~ "\n"`. That code will attempt to coerce `$str` to a string (just as it would in raku). That's what'll be generating the  "Cannot stringify" error.

A search for "Cannot stringify" in the NQP repo only matched some Java code. And I bet you're not running Rakudo on the JVM. That means the error message must be coming from MoarVM.

The same search in the MoarVM repo yields [this line in `coerce.c` in MoarVM](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/9442b1a7c29fd4a25ad50f0a6722e0d04d0f8b5e/src/core/coerce.c#L324).

Looking backwards in the routine containing that line we see [this bit](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/9442b1a7c29fd4a25ad50f0a6722e0d04d0f8b5e/src/core/coerce.c#L295-L299):

```
/* Check if there is a Str method. */
    MVMROOT(tc, obj, {
        strmeth = MVM_6model_find_method_cache_only(tc, obj,
            tc->instance->str_consts.Str);
});
```

This shows the backend, written in C, looking for and invoking a "method" called `Str`. (It's relying on an internal API (6model) that all three layers of the compiler (raku, nqp, and backends) adhere to.)

## Customizing the `Str` method

You'll need to customize the `Str` method as appropriate. For example, to print the class's name if it's a type object, and the value of its `$!bar` attribute otherwise:

```
class foo {
  has $!bar;
  method Str () { self ?? nqp::coerce_is($!bar) !! self.HOW.name(self) }
}
say(foo.new(bar=>42)); # 42
```

Despite the method name, the nqp `say` routine is *not* expecting a raku `Str` but rather an nqp native string (which ends up being a MoarVM native string on the MoarVM backend). Hence the need for `nqp::coerce_is` (which I found by browsing [the nqp ops doc](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/master/docs/ops.markdown)).

`self.HOW.name(self)` is another example of the way nqp just doesn't have the niceties that raku has. You *could* write the same code in raku but the idiomatic way to write it in raku is `self.^name`.

Comment: That answers the question perfectly. I'll have a look at the IRC : I'm not used to this channel. But yes I find SO easier for later people to find the answer : it is scrolled by bot, pretty ...

Answer (score 2):

Currently, what I have is a `list` and `hash` discriminator. It does not work on object.

```
sub print_something ($value, :$indent = 0, :$no-indent=0) {
    if nqp::ishash($value) {
        print_hash($value, :$indent);
    } elsif nqp::islist($value) {
        print_array($value, :$indent);
    } else {
        if $no-indent {
            say($value);
        } else {
            say_indent($indent, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Where

```
sub print_indent ($int, $string) {
    my $res := '';
    my $i := 0;
    while $i < $int {
        $res := $res ~ '  ';
        $i := $i + 1;
    }
    $res := $res ~ $string;
    print($res);
}

sub print_array (@array, :$indent = 0) {
    my $iter := nqp::iterator(@array);
    say_indent($indent, '[');
    while $iter {
        print_value(nqp::shift($iter), :indent($indent+1));
    }
    say_indent($indent, ']');
}

sub print_hash (%hash, :$indent = 0) {
    my $iter := nqp::iterator(%hash);
    say_indent($indent, '{');
    while $iter {
        my $pair := nqp::shift($iter);
        my $key := nqp::iterkey_s($pair);
        my $value := nqp::iterval($pair);
        print_indent($indent + 1, $key ~ ' => ');
        print_value($value, :indent($indent+1), :no-indent(1));
    }
    say_indent($indent, '}');
}
```